# Unable to install RStudio-Server on Raspberry Pi2

Tags: linux, r, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, rstudio-server

I ran into a problem compiling R-Studio Server on a Raspberry Pi2 (Raspbian/Debian Wheezy). I ran the required scripts to install all dependencies which gave me no error. I than ran `cmake` with:

```
cmake .. -DRSTUDIO_TARGET=Server -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

which returned:

```
-- Boost version: 1.50.0
-- Found R: /usr/lib/R
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/ME/rstudio/build
```

running `sudo make` as stated in the README returns:

```
Buildfile: /home/ME/rstudio/src/gwt/build.xml

ext:
```

and than hangs. The `top` command gives me 100% CPU load for java on one of the cores until I interrupt the process(CTRL+C).This returns:

```
src/gwt/CMakeFiles/gwt_build.dir/build.make:52: recipe for target 'gwt_build' failed
make[2]: *** [gwt_build] Interrupt
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:93: recipe for target 'src/gwt/CMakeFiles/gwt_build.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/gwt/CMakeFiles/gwt_build.dir/all] Interrupt
Makefile:133: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Interrupt
```

Any idea on how to complete the installation?

I am running R 3.1.2 which works without problem. The system should be up to date as well. Before someone asks about why am I installing an R-Server on a Pi2 I want to say that this is more  a learning exercise for me about how to administer such a system. I have to admit that all this is pretty new to me any help is appreciated.

Comment: You would really be better off using Docker of Vagrant on your PC/Mac/Linux box. It'll be faster and you can compensate for memory issues (which you will have) easier.

Answer (score 0):

Same here at my end: today I interrupted the build process after 8 hours with exactly the same message as outlined!

On my MacOS X box it's getting built like a charm.

EDIT
Just downloaded the most recent closure compiler from the google site (https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/downloads/detail?name=compiler-20131014.zip&can=2&q=), placed it into "src/gwt/tools/compiler/", and now the build process on my rip is on its way as intended to be.

EDIT(2)
When compiling module org.rstudio.studio.RStudio one might run into an "insufficient memory" error; what has done the trick for me was following Brad Peterson's instructions on how to increase the swap space on the raps (http://www.bionoren.com/blog/2013/02/raspberry-pi-crashplan/).

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/swapfile bs=1M count=2048
mkswap /path/to/swapfile
chown root:root /path/to/swapfile
chmod 0600 /path/to/swapfile
swapon /path/to/swapfile
```

But instead of modifying /etc/fstab I added the corresponding entries to /etc/dphys-swapfile.

```
CONF_SWAPSIZE=2048
CONF_SWAPFILE=/path/to/swapfile
```